# Mysql query: filtering records MM from YYYYMMDD

Tags: mysql

I want to filter records based on the month of the available due date.

I am trying with the following query but It's not working.

```
SELECT * FROM m_bills WHERE due_date LIKE substr('201704',4,2)
```

in this example, I just want to filter all records with the month of April "04".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Query Like this `select * from m_bills where monthname(due_date) = 'April'`

[monthname function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_month)